# Position Absolute Problems in Older IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

```
.top_line {
background:#003466;
float:left;
height:107px;
width:100%;
}
.header_logo {
background:url("../images/header.png") top no-repeat;
position: absolute;
height:107px;
width:910px;
}
.page_wrapper {
margin:0px auto;
width:910px;
}

<div class="top_line"></div>
<div class="header_logo" align="center"></div>
<div class="page_wrapper">
```

The header image appears correctly onlayed on top of the background color on FF,Chrome, and newer versions of IE.  However it appears directly to the right of the background-color bar on older versions of IE.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the header_logo into the top_line CSS and ended up with

```
.top_line {
display:inline;
clear: both;
background:#003466;
background-image: url("../images/header.png");
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float:left;
height:107px;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an IE6 issue.

A common workaround is adding:

```
clear: both;
```

or

```
clear: left;
```

or

```
clear: right;
```

depending on your float in the stylesheet.

Add it like so:

```
.top_line {
clear: both;
background:#003466;
float:left;
```

If that does not work then try:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

with and without it.

These are just some things I have done to work around the same problem in IE6.

Comment: To which class?  I've tried a couple combinations with nothing changing